# Updated npm dependencies, now it won't compile

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-redux

I updated a react-redux test project I did a few years ago to all the newest versions of the npm dependencies, but now I can't compile it. When I run `npm run dev` I get the error:

```
ERROR in ./js/client.js 10:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders                                                                         
| const app = document.getElementById('app')
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
|   <Layout />
| </Provider>, app);
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

My `webpack.config.js` looks like

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/client.js",
  module: {
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
  }
};
```

I know this worked a few years ago, but I also know that the JavaScript world moves pretty quickly. I googled the message, but all the hits I found have to do with `.jsx` file extensions, and I don't have any of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what previous versions of packages you were on, but `webpack` has moved towards decoupling `loaders` from core. So, you have to install them separately.

You add loaders into the `module` section of the `webpack.config.js` file. More info and a tutorial here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#loaders

`babel-loader` is just about the most popular one for `.js` and/or `.jsx` these days. https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader/v/8.0.0-beta.1

Give it a shot, here's how it might look after installing with `yarn add babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-react -D` which will add these dependencies to the dev portion of your `package.json`

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/client.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
  }
};
```

You most likely will have additional errors after this couple steps, but I'm happy to help get your webpack stream up and running if you keep me updated!

**EDIT**

You'll also need a `babel.config.js` (or some similar pattern) at your project root, read more about babel here: https://babeljs.io/

Here's an example:

```
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache(true)

  const presets = [
    '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'
  ]
  // add any more presets you need above as shown

  const plugins = [
    // add any plugins you need here
  ]
  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to add two babel plugins - ` ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]` but otherwise this got it to compile. It's still not working right, but that might be a topic for another question.